# Drag & Drop from TableView to Another View in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, drag-and-drop, swift2

I'm trying to copy an item from one UITableView to another View and  I've been banging my head over this for the past 2 days and still i am not able to figure out how to accomplish this.

Here is a little sketch of my UI architecture

[image]

Here is what i am doing

1. Long Press on a row in the tableview
2. Create a snapshot of the image in the cell when long pressed
3. Drag the snapshot to the View(Green area) outside the table view
4. When released check whether the snapshot was dropped in the Green View Area.

I am able to do till the point of snapshot creation and when i try to drag the snapshot, i am not able to get the points in which the snapshot is dragged. When the drag is released, i need to check whether the last point of drag was inside the DROP AREA (Green Color).

Can anyone give some insights on how to solve the problem with some sample code...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: If you have further questions to the codes, or part of it, just write me a comment, I will write you back in a couple hours....

Comment: @Jobins John can you give me objective c version of this code?

Comment: Can you please post your working code here.. I too have same requirement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently I does't have the time to test the code, but it should be enough to make sense.... You can do something like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

    private var dragView: UIView?
    @IBOutlet weak var dropZone: UIView!

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        let lpGestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didLongPressCell))
        cell.contentView.addGestureRecognizer(lpGestureRecognizer)

        return cell
    }

    func didLongPressCell (recognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        switch recognizer.state {
        case .Began:
            if let cellView: UIView = recognizer.view {
                cellView.frame.origin = CGPointZero
                dragView = cellView
                view.addSubview(dragView!)
            }
        case .Changed:
            dragView?.center = recognizer.locationInView(view)
        case .Ended:
            if (dragView == nil) {return}

            if (CGRectIntersectsRect(dragView!.frame, dropZone.frame)) {
                if let cellView: UIView = (dragView?.subviews[0])! as UIView {
                    cellView.frame.origin = CGPointZero
                    dropZone.addSubview(cellView)
                }

                dragView?.removeFromSuperview()
                dragView = nil

                //Delete row from UITableView if needed...
            } else {
                //DragView was not dropped in dropszone... Rewind animation...
            }
        default:
            print("Any other action?")
        }
    }

}
```

**Update on comment:**

sure, one possibility would be to tag the fields... like this:

```
private let imageViewTag: Int = 997
private let textLabelTag: Int = 998
private let detailTtextLabelTag: Int = 999

//...

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    //...
    cell.imageView?.tag = imageViewTag
    cell.textLabel?.tag = textLabelTag
    cell.detailTextLabel?.tag = detailTtextLabelTag
    //...

}

func didLongPressCell (recognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    //...
    case .Ended:
    let cellImageView: UIImageView? = recognizer.view?.viewWithTag(imageViewTag) as? UIImageView
    let cellTextLabel: UITextField? = recognizer.view?.viewWithTag(textLabelTag) as? UITextField
    let cellDetailTextLabel: UITextField? = recognizer.view?.viewWithTag(detailTtextLabelTag) as? UITextField
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Neo... I was able to solve the problem with some modifications to your answer. But your answer really helped me in solving the problem.

Comment: No problem mate, have fun with it... (And don't forget my up vote...) :-)

Comment: Is there any option to access the elements of the long presses cell in didLongPressCell function. Suppose i have an image view in the long pressed cell and i want to access that in that function. Is there any way?

Comment: Is there any option without giving tags?

Comment: Hmm in this constitution I don't think there is an option without giving tags... Because you are moving just an UIView... Maybe if you subclass the contentView, giving it the textfields and imageviews as properties may be a way... But this would be a lot more code / work... I don't think thats a good idea... Is there a reason you don't want to do it with tags?

Comment: I tried adding tags and that didn't work for me. Its giving an error.

Comment: I Need to See your Code... Could you give me a gist or something like that?

Comment: Can you share your email id or something so that i can share

Comment: @Neo I need objective c version of this code, Could you help me

Comment: //DragView was not dropped in dropszone... Rewind animation...

How to rewind back to the same position of dragged cell? Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

The path of the righteous man is beset of all sides by the complexity.
In case you are manly enough

1. ditch ios 10 and earlier support raising deployment target to ios 11
2. Adopt UITableViewDragDelegate protocol
   2.1 [optionally] enable dragInteractionEnabled = true for table
   to have this working in iphone (by default drag works only on ipad)
3. Study https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/drag_and_drop/making_a_view_into_a_drop_destination
   to check how to make green area a drop destination
4. Watch about 4 drag and drop related videos in wwdc 2017 or go through
   their ascii versions

As a bonus you can have drag and drop working between apps rather than
just inside your app.