# Drag and Drop Image from UITableView to UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift

In UIViewControler, I have both UITableView and UICollectionView. In UITableView, it has UIImageView and Label. I want to drag the image from UITableView and drop into UICollectionView ( UICollectionView has only UIImageView).
I have been looking around and cannot find the solution in Swift 3.
Any one have any idea, please help.
Thank you.

Comment: That's a pretty broad request. I'd suggest you start by searching for `uitableview drag and drop swift` ... you'll find many examples and tutorials. Then search for 'uicollectionview drag and drop swift` ... you'll also find plenty of examples. Go through some examples and tutorials for each, and then combine the process. If you run into ***specific*** problems implementing your code, come back and ask *those* questions.

Comment: I found some projects that drag image from CollectionView to View, and reordering the TableView Cell. I found nothing that interacts between TableView and CollectionView, or even dragging image from TableView to View. If you have any snipes about "dragging image from TableView to View", I will try to figure out the others. Thanks

Comment: Here is one for `TableView to View`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38323948/drag-drop-from-tableview-to-another-view-in-swift ... Here is one for `CollectionView to ColelctionView`: http://blog.karmadust.com/drag-and-drop-between-uicollectionviews/ ... and these are just two of many, many search results. Start with `Table->View`, then `Collection->Collection`, then take what you learn from the first part and combine it with what you learn from the second part.

Comment: Thank you. will try to combine them. Anyway, if I want to copy the image by dragging without remove the image from tableView. what method I should use in this case. Thank again

Comment: I got it worked, Thanks @DonMag

Answer (score -1):

You have to use UICollectionViewDragDelegate, UICollectionViewDropDelegate, UITableViewDropDelegate and UITableViewDragDelegate.

I recommend you to watch this Drag and Drop video from WWDC17:

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/223/

You have the code of the demo here:

https://developer.apple.com/sample-code/wwdc/2017/Drag-and-Drop-in-UICollectionView-and-UITableView.zip

I hope it helps you!